# guitarix can't connect to qjackctl on ubuntu 21.10

Tags: jack, 21.10

yesterday I upgraded my ubuntu to 21.10 and it seems first bug found - guitarix can't connect to qjack

this is error in terminal when starting guitarix (qjack running):

```
Cannot mmap shm segment /jack-1000-0 (*temporary unavailable)
Map shared memory segments exception
JackShmReadWritePtr1::~JackShmReadWritePtr1 - Init not done for -1, skipping unlock
JackShmReadWritePtr::~JackShmReadWritePtr - Init not done for 0, skipping unlock

*translated from my language as good as I can
```

there is also message box with text: [time] Jack Init *** unknown jack server communication error

So I press Start jack in guitarix - qjack window apears in front and than a while nothing, later there is error message box from guitarix saying the same sentence as before + main *** I really tried to get jack up and running, sorry ...

in terminal same error but few more times

*edit:*

I noticed that in qjack log there apears these messages:

```
9:09:16.697 *layout connection JACK changed.
19:09:16.751 *layout connection JACK changed.
Thu Oct 21 19:09:16 2021: New client 'gx_head_amp' with PID 15173
Thu Oct 21 19:09:16 2021: Client 'gx_head_amp' with PID 15173 is out

*translated
```

*edit 2:*

so it seems no answers yet... I was reading trough some articles about qjack and it appeared that there could be some problem with privileges, so I tried to run:

first qjackctl as sudo and guitarix as normal user -> except all my config in jack was away, nothing different

second qjackctl as sudo and guitarix as sudo -> worked, but as I said, all config away, also quite weird running such apps as root

third time I tried to run qjack as user and guitarix as root, but also didn't work

so from this I assume, that with update there had to be some change in probably group audio

Comment: AskUbuntu is not a bug tracker, if you find a bug, file a bug report against the package in question, so the developers can take care. But I'm not sure if this is a bug at all, since on my fresh installation of Ubuntustudio 21.10 guitarix works just fine with all my previous settings. Check your configuration, are you in the audio group? Is the audio group setup correctly? Please see [here](https://jackaudio.org/faq/linux_rt_config.html) if the mentioned files exist and are correct on your system.

Comment: thanks for the link, turns out there was missing audio.conf file :D

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu. This is a question answer site. Please don't put SOLVED in the question title. Feel free to answer your own question by clicking the button **Answer your own question** and provide a detailed answer. Then accept your answer as correct by clicking on the gray check mark ✓ next to your answer and turn it green ✅. This will mark your question as solved and help others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So to fix this problem I just edited (created) file /etc/security/limits.d/audio.conf, I wrote there:

```
@audio   -  rtprio     95
@audio   -  memlock    unlimited
```

if I get it right, it makes audio group users have unlimited memory + high priority for processes

To apply changes, user has to log out